# Query MAX function not working

Tags: php, mysql, max

I need to fetch the highest value from a mysql db column. It's a timestamp. Using mysql MAX function it's not working, bellow you can see the code:

```
//Create new db object
$db = new Db();

//Query
$qr_changelog = $db->query("
    SELECT MAX(log_datetime) FROM ca_change_log
");

//Fetch result
$last_change = $qr_changelog->get('log_datetime');

//Print result
echo "Last Change:" . $last_change;
```

If I run the query without MAX function it works (but obviously returns all values). If I run the query from mysql server console it works. Apache log shows no errors.

I also tried with mysqli:

```
$db1 = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'passwd', 'db');

if($db1->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db1->connect_error . ']');
}

$qr_changelog = $db1->query("
    SELECT MAX(log_datetime) FROM ca_change_log");

while($row = $qr_changelog->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['log_datetime'] . '<br />';
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the SQL and limite the value if You Sant the max value. Something like this: `SELECT log_datetime FROM ca_change_log order by log_datetime dec limite (1)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this:

```
SELECT MAX(log_datetime) AS something FROM ca_change_log  GROUP BY log_datetime

$qr_changelog->get('something');
```

Comment: @TomaszBanasiak Thank you. So much chopping between languages and flavours does this.

Comment: Use SELECT MAX(log_datetime) AS something FROM ca_change_log GROUP BY log_datetime to get only 1 result

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried but didn't work. I must be some newbie mistake from my part.